# Difference between "saying" and "having said", in referring to the past

Tags: tenses

What is the difference between these two sentences?

*I felt/feel sorry for saying nasty things about her previously*.

*I felt/feel sorry for having said nasty things about her previously*.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Obviously the difference between _felt_  and _feel_ depends on whether you are talking about your feelings in the past or now. Whether you say _sorry for saying_ or _sorry for having said_ makes no significant difference to the meaning.

Comment: They are sentences, not expressions.

Comment: Thank you, Kate Bunting. That means I could use either as they basically mean the same thing. Am I right? (feel/felt is not my main concern, this is).